# python iterate over a list, remove item, why result is not empty?

Tags: python, list, loops

I tried this:

```
mylist = range(20)

for item in mylist:
    mylist.remove(item)

len(mylist) == 20
```

Why the result is not [] ?

Comment: .remove returns a copy of the list. Use mylist = mylist.remove(item)

Comment: Repeat after me. Never, ever modify the list that you are iterating over, it causes all kinds of problems. Rather, iterate over the original list and modify a copy (using the index).

Comment: No , .remove() returns a None, and modified the list. @Stiffo